# Flag as off-topic + migrate also suggests I flagged as duplicate

Tags: bug, flags, duplicate-questions, migration

I flagged [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21301165/914686) as being off-topic and requested it be migrated to [TeX - LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com). However, it's suggesting I flagged it as a duplicate and/or should be closed:

[image]

While closing as off-topic includes a listing for a possible duplicate

[image]

it seems incorrect.